# how to use a library that's compiled for python 2.7 in python 2.4

Tags: python, xml-parsing, python-2.4

I want to use a library which is available from python 2.7 onwards on a system with python 2.4. I cannot upgrade the system to python 2.7, as many other libraries and softwares are written in python 2.4.
For instance, i want to use the xml.eTree library in python 2.4.
Can i take the source code of that library and do few changes and compile it on 2.4 ? If yes, could you please tell how to proceed?

Comment: `import whatever from __future__`?

Comment: but how does pythonn 2.4 knows about what all the modules are present in python 2.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to upgrade the system Python. Install your own local version of 2.7 into your home directory, create a virtualenv using that version, and install your libraries there.

Comment: could you please explain more on this. I am new to python.